# making texreg (LaTex or HTML table output) work with splm model

Tags: extract, spatial, texreg

My post follows after the one below, which remains unanswered.

[In R - How to use spml objects in Stargazer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582378/in-r-how-to-use-spml-objects-in-stargazer)

Since stargazer does not work with splm models, I tried texreg, as suggested in the post above. basically these is what I do:

```
    library(spdep)
library(texreg)
    fm<-Y ~ x+m+s+slag(x,listw=w.listw) #formula to be applied
            #Model1- 1st Spatial RE model 
         m1 <- spml(formula=fm, data = spatialpaneldata,listw = w.listw, model="random", spatial.error="b", lag=T)

            #Model2 - 2nd Spatial RE model
        m2<- spml(formula=fm, data = spatialpaneldata,listw = w.listw, model="random", spatial.error = "kkp",  lag=T)
```

then I apply texreg to get a nice table results output for my paper

```
    texreg(list(m, m2), dcolumn = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE,use.packages = FALSE, label = "tab:3", caption = "Two spatial models.",float.pos = "hb!")
```

however, i get the error below:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"splm"’
>
```

How can I make (extract) `texreg` applicable to spatial panel models, or `splm` models?

I hope I can get some help..